# How to invalidate specific cached Amazon S3 file with s3cmd command?

Tags: amazon-s3

I use `s3cmd` to copy local content to remote bucket with:

```
s3cmd --acl-public --cf-invalidate -M \
      --add-header="Cache-Control: max-age=604800" \
      --cf-invalidate \
      --no-encrypt \
      sync $LOCAL_FOLDER s3://$REMOTE_BUCKET
```

`--cf-invalidate` makes sure that old cached file with same name as the file being copied is invalidated. However, some cached files copied before won't be copied any more and thus won't be invalidated. How can I invalidate specific cached file?